# Which Application is listening on particular port

Tags: kali-linux, nmap

I tried to scan a particular IP in my network with the following command:

```
nmap -sV --script=banner X.X.X.X
```

and the result was :

```
25/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
80/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
443/tcp open  tcpwrapped
```

Now, I want to know what application and/or services are behind these port?

Comment: If you have access to that machine, use `lsof`. If you don't, ask the administrator.

Comment: What OS was the target?  The fact it most likely has a mail server would suggest it's probably Linux unless it's a Windows server?  If it is Windows, `netstat -ano | find "LISTEN` will give you the pids of the processes that are listening. You can then use tasklist or taskmanager to resolve these back to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of standard TCP ports can be found in Wikipedia
[List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

More specifically :

- 25 : Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP), used for email routing between mail servers
- 80 : Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
- 443 : Hypertext Transfer Protocol over TLS/SSL (HTTPS)

Your web server is the one listening on the last two ports.